# Add custom directory in URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

How can i add custom "directory" in my URL for pages and posts?

So the main website url is: `http://www.example.com`, but when i go to a page I want this kind of URL: `http://www.example.com/SOMETHING/new_page`

How can I put that "SOMETHING" in URL without affecting Wordpress functions?

Comment: Almost 7 years later... You can achieve what you are after using custom URLs that include a category: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-include-category-and-subcategory-in-wordpress-urls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your

`Dashboard => Settings => Permalinks`

click on `Custom Structure` and paste this `/something/%postname%/`

And you can replace `something`

It will add the `something` keyword before pages and post url slugs.

Comment: Is it possible to have the directory only for some pages ?

Comment: Asking the same. Can you put different folders for different articles?

Comment: @Xonatron There is no native possibility. But one can extend it via hooks or so. Or you can try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ (not used myself).

Answer (score 0):

You have to select "Custom structure" and add a prefix to your permalink structure in the permalinks settings, like:

```
/SOMETHING/%postname%/
```

Here is the the [Wordpress Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure) that explain how to choose permalink structure.

Comment: Can you modify it on a per-article basis?