# Display categorised url

Tags: url-rewriting

I visited [Add custom directory in URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123865/add-custom-directory-in-url). The whole site will have that setting. I want some pages under SOMETHING1 and some pages under SOMETHING2. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

O' I got it from godaddy.com.

1. A blank page should be made first with the name SOMETHING1.
2. Open the desired page, say New_Page.
3. Open Page Attributes on the right side and select SOMETHNG1 from the Parent dropdown.

This will create the permalink like this:
domain/SOMETHING1/New_Page.

The same procedure can be done in case of other pages.